# Java - remove() in custom iterator and linked list

Tags: java, iterator

I am an absolute Java beginner, and have been working on getting the remove() for a custom iterator (for a linked list) working. I have been trying for many hours getting this to work. My issue is that the iterated items are not removed. The method does however (correctly) throw an IllegalState-error, when there is no previous element.

I would appreciate if you guys could have a look at it, and indicate what may be wrong, because I cannot work myself around it, and have tried all kinds of different things.
One question: is the problem that I set next as head in constructor? Because if I don't, the list is not iterated at all!

Thank you so much in advance.

====================================================================

```
public class CustListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

private Node<E> head;
private Node<E> next;
private Node<E> prev;
private CustList<E> list;

public CustListIterator(CustList<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    head = list.head;
    next = head;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return next != null;                 
}

public E next() {
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException ();
    prev = next;
    E element = next.element;
    next = next.next;
    return element;
}

public void remove() { 
    if(prev == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    else {
        if(prev == head){
            head = prev.next;
            list.head = head;
        }
        next = prev.next;
        prev = null;
        list.listSize--;
    }
}
```

=============================================================================

Iteration of

```
CustList<String> items = new CustList<String>();
items.add("aaaaaa");
items.add("bbbbb");
items.add("ccc");
items.add("dddddddd");
items.add("eeeeee");

System.out.println("List iterated:");
Iterator<String>  it = items.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
    it.remove();
}

System.out.println("Size: " + items.size());
```

=============================================================================

Still gives however

```
List iterated:
aaaaaa
bbbbb
ccc
dddddddd
eeeeee
Size: 0
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: They are getting removed, thats why the resulting size is 0. You are just printing them before they are removed.

Comment: @jliars, I was just about to say that, but then I wasn't sure of OPs desired output

Comment: Dear peeskillet, dear jlars62. Thank you for taking the time to answer me. Maybe I was not thinking correctly. It is true that I print them before I run remove method, I somehow failed to realize this. If you had a quick glance at the code, would you conclude that the remove method looks allright generally?

Comment: @peeskillet Yeah its not completely clear...

Comment: @User, I say test it out and see if you get your desired outcome.